# how to allow duplicate key in hash map inside hash map

Tags: java, hash

My code is that I read document , then I get the term frequency from each doc such as :

Term D1:Term Frequency in D1 , D2:Term Frequency in D2.

```
    HashMap<String, HashMap<Integer, Integer>> Index =new 
         HashMap<String ,HashMap<Integer,Integer>>();

           String Docs [] = {"word1.txt","word2.txt"};

    for(int i1=0 ; i1<words.length;i1++)

  { String x=words[i1];

    if(!Index.containsKey(x) || Index.isEmpty())
    {
      HashMap<Integer, Integer> inner = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

      inner.put(i, 1);

      Index.put(x,inner);

    }

  else if(Index.containsKey(x))
    {
        if(Index.get(x).containsKey(i))

        { 
                 HashMap<Integer, Integer> inner = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
                    Collection<Integer> value= Index.get(x).values() ;

                   int count=(int) value.toArray()[0];

                   count=count+1;

                   inner.put(i, count);

                   Index.put(x,inner);

        }

        else if(!Index.get(x).containsKey(i))

        {
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> inner = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

          inner.put(i, 1);

            Index.put(x,inner);

            }


    }
```

Word1 contain :welcome welcome build story welcome

word2 contain : build

My output :

> build : {1=1}  welcome : {0=3}  story : {0=1}

I want to my output to be this

> build : {0=1 ,1=1}  welcome : {0=3}  story : {0=1}

so why is not allowing this to happen

Comment: Please indent your code so that it's readable.

Answer (score 3):

A `HashMap`, and a `Map` in general, can contain only unique keys, no duplicates. A map type that allows duplicate keys is called a *multimap*. There is no implementation in the Java standard library, but the excellent Guava has [a `Multimap` interface](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) with various implementations.